# Laravel Upgrade to 5.8 Fails - Could not delete ...vendor/nexmo/client/phpcs.xml:

Tags: php

When trying to upgrade from Laravel 5.8 to 5.9, I get this Runtime Error:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                      
  Could not delete /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/nexmo/client/phpcs.xml:
```

I may not be even using nexmo so I'm thinking it came with an older install of Laravel.

I'm currently upgrading in the Cloud9 IDE, and have done so successfully in the past so I don't think it is a permissions error.

Any ideas what might be causing this?  Thank you..8